# Error: XML must start and end with the same entity

Tags: xml, blogs

```
</div>
{/block:Answer}

{block:PermalinkPage}
        <div style="margin-top:20px;">{block:Date}
            <b>Posted:</b> {Month} {DayOfMonth}, {Year} &bull; {12Hour}:{Minutes} {CapitalAmPm}{/block:Date}{block:NoteCount}<br><b>With:</b>&nbsp;{NoteCountWithLabel}{/block:NoteCount}<br>{block:HasTags}<b>Filed Under:</b>{block:Tags} #{Tag}{/block:Tags}{/block:HasTags}{/block:Date}
        </div>
{/block:PermalinkPage}


    {block:PostNotes}
        {PostNotes}
    {/block:PostNotes}

{/block:Posts}

{block:IfInfiniteScroll}</div>{/block:IfInfiniteScroll}
</div>
</body>
</html/>
```

I think code I'm using is poorly formatted but again I have no idea what I'm doing!

Answer (score 1):

If that's your whole XML, then you're missing at least the following at the top of your block:

```
<html>
<body>
```

You also start with a closing `</div>` which should probably be `<div>` unless there's more to your example.